# Why ul element was moved out of pre element in php domdocument?

Tags: php

I have a HTML like follow:

```html
<pre>
  <code>
   some code
   <div></div>
  </code>
  <ul>
     <li>1</li>
  </ul>
</pre>
others
```

And parse it via DOMDocument.

After I run this:

```php
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);
echo $doc->saveHTML();
```

The `ul` element was removed out of `pre` element:

```html
<pre>
  <code>
   some code
   <div></div>
  </code>
</pre>
<ul>
 <li>1</li>
</ul>
others
```

Why and How to keep it the same?

Please see [demo](https://3v4l.org/qpa5i#v7.4.25) for detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Why?**

According to the specification, a UL element cannot belong to the content of a [PRE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/pre) element.

Permitted content: [Phrasing content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#phrasing_content)

> Phrasing content is a subset of flow content that defines the text and
> the markup it contains, and can be used everywhere flow content is
> expected. Runs of phrasing content make up paragraphs.
>
> Elements belonging to this category are <abbr>, <audio>, <b>,
> <bdo>, <br>, <button>, <canvas>, <cite>, <code>, <command>,
> <data>, <datalist>, <dfn>, <em>, <embed>, <i>, <iframe>,
> <img>, <input>, <kbd>, <keygen>, <label>, <mark>, <math>,
> <meter>, <noscript>, <object>, <output>, <picture>, <progress>,
> <q>, <ruby>, <samp>, <script>, <select>, <small>, <span>,
> <strong>, <sub>, <sup>, <svg>, <textarea>, <time>, <u>, <var>,
> <video>, <wbr> and plain text (not only consisting of white spaces
> characters).

This can be seen in the warning message after calling `$doc->loadHTML($html)`:

> Warning:  DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Unexpected end tag : pre in Entity

[demo](https://3v4l.org/N4vcZ#v7.4.25)

**How to keep it the same?**

If you still need to work only with a fragment of the DOM structure that does not meet the specification, use the `createDocumentFragment` and `appendXML` functions:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$docFragment = $doc->createDocumentFragment();
$docFragment->appendXML($html);
$doc->appendChild($docFragment);
echo $doc->saveHTML();
```

[demo](https://3v4l.org/sU0sB#v7.4.25)

Comment: Oh, no, It not work. see https://3v4l.org/qpa5i#v7.4.25

Comment: See the modified second part of the answer.

Comment: Well, sometimes it works, sometimes not. Maybe My HTML is not correct (it's too long). I'll do some more digging. Thanks.